# Trigger para otimização de tabela

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Estou tentando criar uma `trigger` que roda o comando ***OPTIMIZE*** do MySQL.

Em suma, tenho uma tabela A e criei uma tabela B que gravará um `datetime` onde esse valor será atualizado toda vez que que a tabela A receber o comando OPTIMIZE.

A Trigger iria

Tentei o seguinte código, mas, o MySQL acusa erro e não acho a solução.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER optimizechattable AFTER UPDATE ON lz_chat_archive FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE @qtd int = 0; 
    DECLARE @MAXDATE DATE; 
    DECLARE @DATAATUAL DATE;

    SET @qtd = ( SELECT count(c.time) as qtd FROM lz_chats_table_optimize as c );

    SET @MAXDATE = ( SELECT MAX(c.time) FROM lz_chats_table_optimize as c );
    SET @DATAATUAL = (SELECT GETDATE());

    IF(@quantidade <= 0)
        optimize table lz_chat_archive;
        /* break execution */
    END IF;

     /* adaptar para  , se diferença for maior que x horas, executar if*/
    IF (@MAXDATE > @DATAATUAL)

        UPDATE lz_chats_table_optimize as c SET c.time = @DATAATUAL where id = 1
        optimize table lz_chat_archive;

    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Qual erro o Mysql acusa?

Comment: Boa tarde  , MySql retorna esse erro: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'qtd int = 0; 
    DECLARE MAXDATE DATE; 
    DECLARE DATAATUAL DATE;

   ' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está na linha  `DECLARE @qtd int = 0;` não pode setar o valor dessa forma, precisa usar o `SET`

Desse modo:

```
DECLARE @qtd int; 
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATE; 
DECLARE @DATAATUAL DATE;

SET @qtd = 0;
```

Alem disso, está utilizando `@quantidade` no lugar de `@qtd` no seu `if`

Comment: Boa noite, quanto a variavel foi o corretor que auto completou para quantidade hehe. Retirei os DECLARE  , o erro mudou. 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'optimize table lz_chat_archive;
        /* break execution */
    END IF;

' at line 10

Comment: [Veja esse link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/if_then.php) de como declarar uma condição

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia  ,

Resolvi o problema criando uma procedure (o MySql não aceita os comandos **optimize**  na trigger).E criei uma **trigger** para chamar a **procedure** toda vez que atualizar a tabela.

Segue codigo completo:

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE qtd int(11);
    DECLARE lastatt DATETIME;
    DECLARE diffhour INT(11);

    SET qtd = (SELECT count(id) FROM lz_chats_table_optimize where id = 1 );

    if qtd <= 0 THEN

        SELECT "Inserindo dados na tabela de controle de atualização";
        INSERT INTO lz_chats_table_optimize (`time` ) VALUES ( NOW() );
        SELECT "Otimizando tabela alvo";
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_archive;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_posts;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_requests;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_forwards;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitor_browser_urls;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitor_browsers;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_event_triggers;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitors;
        OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitor_chats;
    ELSE

        SET lastatt = (SELECT c.time FROM lz_chats_table_optimize as c where id = 1 );
        SET diffhour = ( SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW() , lastatt)) );  

        IF diffhour >= 1 THEN

            SELECT "Atualizando dados na tabela de controle de atualização";
            UPDATE lz_chats_table_optimize set `time` = now() where id = 1;
            SELECT "Otimizando tabela alvo";
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_archive;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_posts;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_requests;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_chat_forwards;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitor_browser_urls;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitor_browsers;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_event_triggers;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitors;
            OPTIMIZE TABLE lz_visitor_chats;

        ELSE

            SELECT "Não há necessidade de otimizar a tabela";

        END IF;

    END IF;

END
```